# Android push up notification cant parse some html code like MsoNormal

Tags: android, html, notifications, push

i m tying to set text from message to notification like

```
mNotifyBuilder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.no_subject))
               .setContentText(Html.fromHtml(message.getMessageText()))
```

but message include some html and Html.fromHtml put it in notification as string.
Is any ways to resolve it? because WebView doing it correctly with text/html.

Answer (score 0):

Android TextView used in default notification layout supports only some of html tags, those are:

```
br, p, ul, li, div, span, strong, b, em, cite, dfn, i, big, small, font, blockquote, tt, a, u, del, s, strike, sup, sub, h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6, img
```

To change the default layout you could create custom push notification layout. But RemoteView used in it dose not support WebView. Only

```
AnalogClock Button Chronometer ImageButton ImageView ProgressBar
TextView ViewFlipper ListView GridView StackView AdapterViewFlipper
```

Not sure what data would you like to show to users. But I don't think it would be possible to display your html content without some string manipulation like for example deleting/modifying unsupported tags. If you would like to show users some advance html page in the notification, then I think it's impossible.